# перебор массива и функция

Tags: php

Этот цикл перебора массива почему то внутри  функции не работает, а если убрать функцию, то цикл работает отлично. Я не могу сообразить, почему так?

```
$massive = [1,2,3,4,5];

function opa(...$numbers){        

    for($a = 0; $a < count($massive); $a++){                                                
        echo $massive[$a];
    }
}

opa(...$massive);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что в функции ты оперируешь переменной с именем `$massive`, хотя на вход подана переменная с именем  `$numbers`

Comment: Точно, спасибо!

Comment: а что такое "оперируешь" ?

Comment: "пользоваться чем-либо"